# Not able to see JSON Editor even after installing JSON Editor Plugin in eclipse

Tags: json, eclipse-plugin, editor

I am using eclipse neon version.
I installed JSON Editor Plugin using Eclipse Marketplace. It installed successfully.

I can see entry for JSON Editor Plugin in Installed Software list.
This is developed by Boothen Technology.

But still I can not find JSON Editor in the list of editors.
It used to work fine in the past.
I tried reinstalling many times but did not get success.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with my .plugins folder because of corrupt eclipse workspace.
This was present in the following location

```
<Eclipse-Workspace>/.metadata/.plugins
```

Shutdown Eclipse.

Delete content present inside .plugins folder.

Restart Eclipse.

Import projects again from the workspace.

JSON Editor mapped to the .json files.

The same thing also solved the problem for .sh files also.